# Plane deforming while using solidify modifier

Tags: modeling, modifiers, solidify-modifier

I modelled a plane into an object , I am trying to increase the thickness so I tried using the solidify modifier, but once I tried to use it my plane became distorted and uneven

Plane in object and edit mode before applying solidify ↓↓↓

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

plane after applying the solidify modifier  ↑ ↑ ↑

my modifier settings ↓↓↓

[image]

You can download my .blend file from this link https://we.tl/t-e7WxuNR8ab

Answer (score 1):

You have some inverted normals, go in *Edit* mode, select all and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>.

Comment: It worked! Thanks